# How to get data from variable in ln laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

My database table has name, phone, email etc.. fields. Now I store particular field data in different variable and pass them. Here is my code. I tried it from controller function. What should I do?

```
$var = DB::select("SELECT * FROM reg where email = '$c_email' and Password = '$c_pass' and type = '$c_type'");
$var2 = $var->name;
$var3 = $var->phone;
return redirect('farmer')->with('key', $var2)->with('key2', $var3);
```

Comment: Where do you want to get the data?

Answer (score 2):

You may try the given way

```
return view('farmer',compact('var2', 'var3'));
```

> Here 'farmer' is your view page

http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/03/09/passing-multiple-variables-into-a-laravel-5-view/

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `redirect()->with()`, you're flashing data to the session. So to get this data after redirect, use [`session()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#using-the-session) helper:

```
session('key')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Answer (score 0):

use this code. if farmer is view part. or use view part name.

```
$var=DB::table('reg')
             ->where('email', $c_email)
             ->where('password ', $c_pass)
             ->where('type', $c_pass)
             ->select('name','phone')
             ->first();

return view('farmer')->with('var', $var);
```

get data in view part,
   $name=$var->name;
   $phone=$var->phone;